# Google API Client Library in Java set-up error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-client

I am trying to download the source-code of Google API Client Library written in Java and perform some local developments. However, setting up the project seems to be a big hurdle.

I meticulously followed the instructions written here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/contribute

However, I am still getting a bunch of error, possibly due to maven settings. I have tried updating the projects and downloading sources and Javadoc. Still, I am getting these errors. Spend nearly 3-4 hours.

The main errors are of these kinds:

1.`Missing artifact com.google.api-client:google-api-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0-SNAPSHOT`

Error Point:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2.`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (execution: generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)`

Error Point:

```
  <execution>
    <id>generate-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
      <target>
        <mkdir dir="target/generated-test-sources" />
        <exec failonerror="true" executable="protoc">
          <arg value="--java_out=target/generated-test-sources" />
          <arg value="src/test/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/mock_data.proto" />
          <arg value="src/test/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/error_output.proto" />
        </exec>
      </target>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
```

3.`The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/sohamgrad/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client-appengine/1.21.0-SNAPSHOT/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.21.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'`

No error point in this case.

These are the main 3 types of errors. These types of errors are happening in multiple places.

I would appreciate any kind of help in this.

Comment: error 2 is not an issue, are you planning to contribute to the library or do you want to use it on your project?

Comment: I want to contribute and use both. But for now, I am considering the contribution option.